# MingGW with Cython

Tags: python, visual-studio, mingw, cython

I am trying to run code similar to example code at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython#Example on Windows-7 but I am getting error that Visual Studio is needed:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-
build-tools
```

How can I use MinGW to correct this error?

Comment: Is your python version also compiled with MinGW? If not the extension compiled with MinGW will have strange behavior...

Comment: There was a modification to mingw called [mingwpy](https://mingwpy.github.io/) that aimed to be compatible with versions of Python that were compiled with Visual Studio. I think it basically worked until Python 3.5+ (where it got trickier)

Comment: If you can, I would take a look at [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). It makes it really easy to install any mingw packages, and I am using it right now to work with cython on Windows10.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will try these and write back.

Comment: I am looking for an answer with code to apply these.